# How to set partial key in sql server

Tags: sql-server, create-table

I want to create table and set column as partial key

Fox example:
I create 2 column month and year, then I want to set each column as partial key.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.table ADD CONSTRAINT PK_keyname PRIMARY KEY (month, year)
```

That will create a primary key with month and year as the 2 columns that make up the full key.

Comment: so partial key is combining 2 attribute column item as primary key?

Comment: A partial key is (loosely) part of a multi-column primary key.